# How to take user input for list (string or number as an element) in a single line?

Tags: dart

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  int? n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

  print("value of n: $n and run time type: ${n.runtimeType}");
  List<int> list1 = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    list1.insert(i, int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!));
  }
  print("List 1: $list1");
}
```

This is my code.
If I take in put like that:

```
5
1  
2
3
4
5
```

it gives output:

```
value of n: 5 and run time type: int
List 1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to take input like:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

and want the same output. But I do not find any resources for that. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by using space as delimiter and then use map to parse each string into an int.

This way don't need to know number of elements beforehand but if it's necessary to get exactly `n` number of elements in list then you can use `Iterable.take()` method.

```
  List<int> list1 = stdin
          .readLineSync()
          ?.split(RegExp(r'\s+'))
          .map((e) => int.parse(e))
          .take(n)
          .toList() ??
      List<int>.empty();
```